# Hide tier price if special price is available

Tags: magento-1.9, tierprice, special-price

my product have both special price for a period and tier price also. but i want to hide tier price if a special price is available in magento-1.9. now my product display both special price and tier price. please help me any one to solve this problem.

Comment: In which template are you trying to show the special price?

Comment: ultimo template